# How can I prevent iTunes from automatically opening the downloaded audio files?

Tags: macos, itunes, safari, audio

When I download an audio file with Safari, it is automatically opened with iTunes.

How can I do to prevent this ? 
**I would like that nothing happens when an audio file is downloaded.**

My configuration is MacOS 10.8, iTunes 11, and Safari 6.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to provide further details of the actions you are taking, describing in more detail what the problem is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Go to Safari preferences

Disable the Open safe files after downloading

[image]